# Babel configuration for react-native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs

so i am trying to run this `react-native` app built on `expo` i am having trouble configuring things.

here's my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]

}
```

my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "APP NAME",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.25.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "jest-expo": "^37.0.0",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.17",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
    "debug": "open 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=19001'"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^3.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
    "expo": "^37.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-hr-component": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-mock-render": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-paystack": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-webview-bridge": "^0.33.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

so at first i had an error like

```
node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/node_modules/@react-native-community/viewpager/js/index.js: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In node_modules/babel-preset-expo/index.js
```

this got fixed when i remove "babel-preset-expo" from my `.babelrc` and replaced it with the above content now i am having another error like this:

```
SyntaxError: /node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/node_modules/@react-native-community/viewpager/js/index.js: Unexpected token (10:12)

   8 |  */
   9 | 
> 10 | import type {PageScrollState as _PageScrollState} from './types';
     |             ^
  11 | import type {PageScrollEvent as _PageScrollEvent} from './types';
  12 | import type {PageScrollStateChangedEvent as _PageScrollStateChangedEvent} from './types';
  13 | import type {PageSelectedEvent as _PageSelectedEvent} from './types';
Failed building JavaScript bundle
```

so any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**
okay so i have added `"react-native"` to the babel presets array and the previous error i gone but now i got a new error saying:

```
node_modules/react-navigation-deprecated-tab-navigator/node_modules/react-native-tab-view/src/TabViewPagerExperimental.js: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no .babel.rc present, you can create your own. Add whatever else you may need in there just as you would with .babelrc and it should work. I tried this out yesterday on my Expo managed RN app and it seems to have worked.

```
// Filename: .babelrc
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: This was initial answer...

Expo can be created with two workflows. You would get a .babelrc for a bare workflow, and a babel.config.js for a managed workflow.

If you have "babel.config.js" you could try the following instead of worrying about .babelrc

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: ["babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with whith this babel.config.js configurations. I got to this by merging what I read on react-native-paper docs and other npm libraries.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', { loose: true }],
      ],
    },
    production: {
      plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
    },
  },
};
```